# c++ simple input handling (2 arrays of chars separated by a space)

Tags: c++, input, char

my problem is, I'm trying to input an unknown number of pairs:
-the first element of a pair is a word (I cannot use strings, only chars and char*[])
-then there is a space
-the second word(also strings not allowed)
then there is the new line sign

Without using strings, how can I most efficiently input those two words? What to put in the `while(!cin.eof())` loop?

Answer (score 0):

Start here.  I'd read through all of the FAQs on IO if I were you.  It appears to be a simple homework assignment which could be accomplished in several ways, but I think it is better to give you guidance rather than doing your homework for you.
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/input-output.html
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/istream-and-eof.html

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

/* Read a string, split it into two sub-strings with space as the delimiter
   return true if split succeeded otherwise return false

   sample execution:
       input: abc def
       output: *firstWord = abc *secondWord = def
       return value: true 

       input: abc def ghi
       output: *firstWord = abc, *secondWord = def ghi
       return value: true

       input: abc
       output: *firstWord = undefined, *secondWord = undefined
       return value: false
*/

bool readLineAndSplit(char* input, char** firstWord, char** secondWord)
{
    if (*firstWord) 
        delete [] *firstWord;
    if (*secondWord) 
        delete [] *secondWord;

    int len = strlen(input);

    if (!len) 
        return false;

    // pointer to last character in the input
    char* end = input + len - 1; // last character in input

    // read first word, scan until a space is encountered
    char* word = input;
    while(*word != ' ' && word < end ) 
    {
        word++;
    }
    // error: no spaces
    if (word == end) 
    {
        cout << input << " isn't valid! No spaces found!" <<endl;
        return false;
    }
    else 
    {
        *firstWord = new char[(word-input) + 1]; // +1 for '\0'
        *secondWord = new char[(end-word) + 1]; // +1 for '\0'
        strncpy(*firstWord, input, word-input);
        strncpy(*secondWord, word+1, end-word);
        (*firstWord)[word-input] = '\0';
        (*secondWord)[end-word] = '\0';
    }

    return true;
}

int main() 
{
    char input[1024];
    while (true) 
    {
        cin.getline(input, 1024); 
        if (strlen(input) == 0)
            break;
        else
        {
            char* firstWord = NULL, *secondWord = NULL;
            if (readLineAndSplit(input, &firstWord, &secondWord))
            {
                cout << "First Word = " << firstWord << " Second Word = " << secondWord << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Error: " << input << " can't be split!" << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```